# Sorting a list made out of manual structures in lisp

Tags: functional-programming, lisp, common-lisp, clisp

I have a structure in my code

```
(defstruct tree-node char freq )
```

And i have a list of these 'nodes'. For example (#\a 4, #b 5, #q 17) and i want to sort them in descending order. How can i use the sort function. I have written a comparison function but i don't know if this a way to do it.

```
(defun compare()( if( > (tree-node-freq tree-node-freq) T (nil))))
```

When i call the sort function

```
(sort list compare)
```

it says that compare function has no value. By the way i am new to lisp so don't judge please :)

Comment: Probably a good idea to check the documentation/examples for SORT: http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_sort_.htm#sort

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [`sort`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_sort_.htm) function expects a predicate function that takes two arguments and returns a generalized boolean, while the OP code shows a `comparison` function that takes no arguments. There is no reason to use `if` when the comparison itself returns the desired boolean. Also note that the sharp-quote is required to access the function in the `sort` expression, i.e., `(sort list #'compare)` instead of `(sort list compare)`.

You could write the comparison function as:

```
CL-USER> (defun node-greater-p (n1 n2)
           (> (tree-node-freq n1) (tree-node-freq n2)))
NODE-GREATER-P

CL-USER> *nodes*
(#S(TREE-NODE :CHAR #\a :FREQ 4) #S(TREE-NODE :CHAR #\b :FREQ 5)
 #S(TREE-NODE :CHAR #\q :FREQ 17))

CL-USER> (sort *nodes* #'node-greater-p)
(#S(TREE-NODE :CHAR #\q :FREQ 17) #S(TREE-NODE :CHAR #\b :FREQ 5)
 #S(TREE-NODE :CHAR #\a :FREQ 4))
```

You could just as well do this with an anonymous function:

```
CL-USER> *nodes*
(#S(TREE-NODE :CHAR #\a :FREQ 4) #S(TREE-NODE :CHAR #\b :FREQ 5)
 #S(TREE-NODE :CHAR #\q :FREQ 17))

CL-USER> (sort *nodes* #'(lambda (n1 n2) (> (tree-node-freq n1) (tree-node-freq n2))))

(#S(TREE-NODE :CHAR #\q :FREQ 17) #S(TREE-NODE :CHAR #\b :FREQ 5)
 #S(TREE-NODE :CHAR #\a :FREQ 4))
```

But, it would be even better to take advantage of the `:key` argument of the `sort` function which provides a sort key:

```
CL-USER> *nodes*
(#S(TREE-NODE :CHAR #\a :FREQ 4) #S(TREE-NODE :CHAR #\b :FREQ 5)
 #S(TREE-NODE :CHAR #\q :FREQ 17))

CL-USER> (sort *nodes* #'> :key #'tree-node-freq)

(#S(TREE-NODE :CHAR #\q :FREQ 17) #S(TREE-NODE :CHAR #\b :FREQ 5)
 #S(TREE-NODE :CHAR #\a :FREQ 4))
```

Answer (score 1):

If you define your `compare` function in the REPL, we see warnings:

```
(defun compare()( if( > (tree-node-freq tree-node-freq) 
                               T
                               nil)))
; in: DEFUN COMPARE
;     (IF (> (SBCLI::TREE-NODE-FREQ SBCLI::TREE-NODE-FREQ) T NIL))
; 
; caught ERROR:
;   error while parsing arguments to special operator IF:
;     too few elements in
;       ((> (TREE-NODE-FREQ TREE-NODE-FREQ) T NIL))
;     to satisfy lambda list
;       (SB-C::TEST SB-C::THEN &OPTIONAL SB-C::ELSE):
;     between 2 and 3 expected, but got 1
; 
; compilation unit finished
;   caught 1 ERROR condition
COMPARE
```

You put the closing parenthesis of `>` too far away. Instead of `> a b` we only got `> (a) b c`. So the `if` doesn't have a then nor an else clause.

You might want to use an editor with lisp indentation.

#### Compare

Looking at `sort`'s documentation:

```
SORT names a compiled function:
  Lambda-list: (SEQUENCE SB-IMPL::PREDICATE &REST SB-IMPL::ARGS &KEY
                SB-IMPL::KEY)
  Declared type: (FUNCTION
                  (SEQUENCE (OR FUNCTION SYMBOL) &REST T &KEY
                   (:KEY (OR FUNCTION SYMBOL)))
                  (VALUES SEQUENCE &OPTIONAL))
  Documentation:
    Destructively sort SEQUENCE. PREDICATE should return non-NIL if
       ARG1 is to precede ARG2.
  Inline proclamation: MAYBE-INLINE (inline expansion available)
```

It mentions two arguments to the compare function. And indeed, we have an example here with the lambda function: http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_sort_.htm

```
 (setq tester (copy-seq "lkjashd")) =>  "lkjashd"
 (stable-sort tester #'(lambda (x y) (and (oddp x) (evenp y))))
```

Your function must take two arguments, `tree-1` and `tree-2`.

Compare them with `(> (tree-node-freq tree-1) (tree-node-freq tree-2))`.

#### Last bits

```
(nil)
```

Your are calling the "nil" function. Just return `nil`, as you return `T`.

Better yet, use `when`. If when is false, the function implicitly returns nil.

```
(sort list compare)
```

You must reference `compare` as being a function: `#'compare`. See https://lispcookbook.github.io/cl-cookbook/functions.html#referencing-functions-by-name-single-quote--or-sharpsign-quote-